# How do I serialise/deserialise a std::vector<bool> most efficiently?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to write the contents of a `std::vector<bool>` to disk into a binary file. As the `write()` method of many of the STL output streams takes in a pointer to the array itself, as well as the number of bytes to write, for a 'normal' vector I'd end up doing something like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> dataVector = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
std::fstream outStream = std::fstream("vectordump.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
outStream.write((char*) dataVector.data(), dataVector.size() * sizeof(unsigned int));
outStream.close();
```

However, the `std::vector<bool>` is a special case, as the STL implementation is allowed to pack the bools into single bits. The above approach will therefore technically not consistently work, because it's unspecified how the data is precisely laid out in memory.

Is there any way of serialising/deserialising my bool vector without having to pack/unpack the data?

Comment: The solution seems not to be the best, but I used to make a helper vector with integers and used the integer vector for writing/reading. Which values you use for true and false is up to you, but I think there are some trivial options to use ;)

Comment: Even `unsigned int` might have different size, and endianess might differ from platform...

Comment: The simplest solution seems to be not using a bool vector in the first place...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're better off to just translate that vector into `std::vector<std::byte>`/`std::vector<unsigned char>`.

`std::vector<bool>` isn't even required to have contiguous memory so writing starting from `data()` is implementation defined too.

Comment: That's also good to know, thanks! I guess my best option is to manually implement a packed bit vector myself, so that I can be sure about the datatype it contains.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

Sorry.

A good reason to avoid this container!